# Dataframe to JSON

Tags: pyspark

How can I process a dataframe in pyspark and get output as json:

Dataframe:

```
empid empname in out
1      A      1   1
1      A      1   1
```

output required in json:

```
{
id:empid,
name:empname,
in:[1,1],
out:[1,1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward way to convert pyspark datafram to json is first to convert dataframe into pandas dataframe and then store pandas dataframe as json

`pandas_df = df.toPandas()
pandas_df.to_json("jsonfilename.json")`

Comment: What about the manipulation required(as given in the question)